# Adaptive Issuance: Overstaking

Tags: adaptive-issuance

[This article](https://medium.com/the-aleph/a-walkthrough-of-tezos-new-staking-mechanism-4ff0c50a57a8) states the following:

> when limit_of_staking_over_baking is above zero, delegators can stake any amount that they own, even when the value exceeds the limit that the baker has set or the global 5x limit. In this situation, the amount is subject to slashing and the baker is said to be overstaked. This is a bad scenario — worse than overdelegating, as the staker will have their tez frozen with no benefit.

Is it possible to avoid being overstaked? Or if not, what's the main point of setting the limit if delegators can still exceed it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to avoid being overstaked when accepting stakers.

However, we expect stakers to dynamically adjust their stake to avoid overstaking: indeed, there is a penalty associated with overstaking, that you are not getting your fair share of rewards.

This is similar to overdelegation today: it is not possible to prevent it, but we have observed that bakeries in general are not overdelegated.

We expect block explorers to make this situation clear, so that it does not happen.

> what's the main point of setting the limit if stakers can still exceed it?

There are two:

- you can still set it to zero. Then, the staking operation fails, plain and simple. By default, it will be at zero for everyone.
- you may not be comfortable with 5x your own stake, you may want a smaller amount of stake to begin with. In this case, you can set `limit_of_staking_over_baking` to 1, or even 0.1. This is also relevant if you are paying for slashing insurance, but the insurance coverage is limited.

Why does the staking operation not fail when the baker is overstaked? There is no way to implement this correctly. Indeed, a baker can always become overstaked even though they were not when the staking operations took place.